# Woocommerce: redirect (keep) user in cart page after log-in in cart page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

By default, Woocommerce displays the user login box in the checkout page; I wanted it to appear on the cart page as well, so I have added the following to the functions.php file in my theme's directory:

```
// display login form in cart page
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'woocommerce_login_form' );
```

This works, but after the user log-in, he is redirected to his account page; I would like him to be kept at the cart page, which I think can be done by passing a redirect argument, as per the function's architecture:

```
function woocommerce_login_form( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'message'  => '',
        'redirect' => '',
        'hidden'   => false
    );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults  );
    wc_get_template( 'global/form-login.php', $args );
}
```

How can I pass an url as an argument to this function?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it be replicating the function with some changes:

```
// display login form in cart page
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart', 'woocommerce_login_form_in_cart' );

function woocommerce_login_form_in_cart( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'message'  => '',
        'redirect' => '#',
        'hidden'   => false
    );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults  );
    wc_get_template( 'global/form-login.php', $args );      
}
```